# Any way to send just "\n" in Telnet?

Tags: netcat, telnet, nc, xxd

I'm wondering if there's any way to get telnet to send only a `\n`, not a `\r\n`.

For example, if one process is listening on a port like this, to print the bytes of any traffic received:

```
nc -l 1234 |  xxd -c 1
```

Connecting to it from netcat with `nc localhost 1234`, and typing "hi[enter]":

```
0000000: 68  h
0000001: 69  i
0000002: 0a  .
```

Connecting to it from telnet with `telnet localhost 1234`, and typing "hi[enter]"

```
0000000: 68  h
0000001: 69  i
0000002: 0d  .
0000003: 0a  .
```

Telnet is sending 0x0d0a instead of 0x0a for the newline. I understand that this is a CRLF as opposed to LF. It also sends the CRLF if I use `^M` or `^J`.

I thought I had found a solution that directly addresses this problem, by using `toggle crlf`, but even with this option set, Telnet is always sending the `\r\n`. I've also tried this on various telnet clients, so I'm guessing I'm misunderstanding what the toggling is supposed to do.

Any way to send just a `\n` through telnet, with enter or otherwise?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can negotiate *binary mode*. Once in this mode you cannot leave it. Negotiation means the `telnet` client will send a special byte sequence to the server, which you will have to ignore if you are not implementing the protocol.

Subsequent data is sent unchanged, in line mode.  Client:

```
$ telnet localhost 1234
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> set binary
Negotiating binary mode with remote host.
hi
  ^]
telnet> quit
```

and server

```
$ nc -l 1234 |  xxd -c 1 
00000000: ff  .
00000001: fd  .
00000002: 00  .
00000003: ff  .
00000004: fb  .
00000005: 00  .
00000006: 68  h
00000007: 69  i
00000008: 0a  .
```

Your `telnet` client may have an option to start off in binary mode, or you can put an entry in `~/.telnetrc`

```
localhost
 set binary
```

You can apply the binary mode independently in each direction, so you might prefer `set outbinary`.

Answer (score 1):

Not in **telnet**, since the applicable RFC specifies carriage-return/line-feed as the line-ending.  See [Appendix C in RFC 5198](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5198#appendix-C).

Comment: There is another 'applicable RFC' that specifies a binary mode option, when there is no translation.

Comment: [RFC 856](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc856) doesn't mention line-endings.